# In Zapier, how do I get the inputs to my Python "Run Code" action to be passed in as lists and not joined strings?

Tags: python, zapier

In Zapier, I have a "Run Python" action triggered by a "Twitter" event. One of the fields passed to me by the Twitter event is called "Entities URLs Display URL". It's the list of anchor texts of all of the links in the tweet being processed.

Zapier is passing this value into my Python code as a single comma-separated string. I know I can use `.split(',')` to get a list, but this results in ambiguity if the original strings contained commas.

Is there some way to get Zapier to pass this sequence of strings into my code as a sequence of strings rather than as a single joined-together string?

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

At this time, all inputs to a code step are coerced into strings due to the way data is passed between zap steps. This is a great request though and I'll make a note of it internally.

Comment: That's unfortunate. If passing actual sequences is too hard to add, perhaps add JSON encoded versions of these fields? They'd still be strings, but at least they could be parsed unambiguously.

Comment: Totally! I understand it's a pain point. If you predict a lot of commas in twitter anchor text and this is important, the best thing to do is make a little [CLI app](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) that replicates the twitter action. Then you can set the output to be a json string and we won't touch it. I've done this in a couple of places and it works great (outside the added burden of having to interface with twitter yourself when we should take care of that for you)

Comment: Could we half-fix this issue at least by making sure nulls don’t get dropped? i.e. `["foo", "", "", "bar"]` becomes `foo,,,bar`, not `foo, bar`. This is compatible with coercing inputs into strings between action steps. Right now, nulls get dropped, making it completely impossible to reliably access input keys in a dynamic way. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59365846/1292652).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Zapier's catch raw webhook action.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099781/1193450 for a complete description